# How to do indexing data from database using apache solr with glassfish server on linux?

Tags: solr, lucene, glassfish

I want to create a search box in my web app using Apache Lucene and Apache Solr.I am using postgres database and  have to do it with java.

As I new to these concepts (solr,lucene), I am struggling with this. I already installed and configured apache Solr with glassfish.Now I dont know how to start with this, Whether I have to cretae a java project in eclipse or I  have to use Solr admin GUI.

can any one help me on this?

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to make data searchable, you have to first index your data. You can use one of the following ways to index data.

- By using Solr clients such as [Solrj](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)
- If you store your data in relational DB then you can use [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)
- By posting XML or Json messages. [Check here for documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages).

When new data added you can index it using Solr clients (Solrj). You can also search your data using Solrj or any other client libraries.

You can find other [client libraries here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/IntegratingSolr).

Comment: Thanks Parvin,
i have gone through the DataImportHandler and got idea about registering datasources in data-config.xml.
but my doubt is like, shall we do all these using solr admin or creating java project in eclipse...
PLEASE HELP ME ON THIS

Comment: It will be better to use hybrid approach. Use DataImportHandler for full-import and use Solrj to index new added documents.For DataImportHandler you should use Solr admin and for indexing new added documents you should create java project.

Comment: I tried register requestHandler in data-cofig.xml,but when I am opening solar admin its givin Exception
i.e org.apache.solr.common.solrException: RequestHandler init failure
can you help me on this?

Comment: Did you add apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.y.z.jar into lib folder?

Comment: parvin
yeah, I have added jar..still same exception

Comment: Parvin
i solved that exception...but when I am running the url
http://localhost:8080/apache-solr-4.0.0/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true
I am geeting Data Config problem: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed...
Can you help on this?

Comment: HI Parvin
Thank you very much....I succeed in indexing from database using dataimporthandler
Can you tell how can i use this indexed data in web app?

Comment: You can use Solr clients to make search and display responses. You can find the list of clients on the answer.You can easily find sample code for clients on google.

Comment: Yeah parvin, I have gone through the solrj...But As I new to this, am getting some confusion....like I already did indexing data from database, Shall I do again indexing these documents using solrj or shall i start querying the indexes....?
can you explain pls?

Comment: If you indexed data then you don't need to index it again. Just start querying.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you indexed your data. Since you have an index, you can make query.

Comment: Parvin,I am able to query the index.I have id, modelnames of products in my index.My question is how can we search modelnames depends on user data which is enetered in search box?

Comment: Parvin, How can i convert queryrespone from solrj to json?

Answer (score 4):

You can start with [Solr DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) to index the data from postgres to Solr.

For more detailed understanding you can refer to :-
[how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-1](http://solr.pl/en/2010/10/11/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-1/)
[how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-2](http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/01/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-2/)
[how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-3](http://solr.pl/en/2010/11/22/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-how-to-import-data-from-sql-databases-part-3/)

Comment: Thanks Jayendra
I have gone through the link u provided...But i am running the url
http://192.168.1.102:8080/apache-solr-4.0.0/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true I am getting Data Config problem: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
can you help me?

Comment: you xml seems invalid. Check for the proper structure.

Comment: the log would probably mention the file which had errors during loading. The files would mainly be schema.xml, data-config.xml or solrconfig.xml

Comment: Jayendra, How can i convert queryrespone from solrj to json?

Comment: You can use jackson api to convert the object to json. But Solr already provides a JSON Response writer so you can directly fire a query to solr and get response in json instead of using Solrj.

Comment: Jayendra,now i able to query the index,But I am not getting any results when i gave full name of value in field.
Ex:I have Watches in prod_text field.If I give [Prod_text:watch or watche],i am getting results. If i give [prod_text:watches], I am not getting any results....Can u help on this?