# Getting started with Solr, no gettingstarted folder

Tags: solr

I've just installed Solr (will be controlling with Solarium and using to search Nutch queries.)  I'm working through the starting tutorials described here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

When I try to run $ bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/*.json, I get a bunch of errors having to do
with there not being a gettingstarted folder in /solr/. Is this normal? Should I create one?

Answer (score 0):

Replied in [How to do indexing data from database using apache solr with glassfish server on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737581/how-to-do-indexing-data-from-database-using-apache-solr-with-glassfish-server-on)

Try uploading other json file:
[Solr in 5 minutes](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html)

Or [update](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV) the index with curl:

```
cd example/exampledocs

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv --data-binary @books.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

[Check this out also!](https://nowontap.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/solr-ingesting-a-csv-file-part-1/)

Oh and you might find this useful [clearing solr index](http://daniel.hepper.net/blog/2010/11/howto-clear-solr-index/)